# Symbolic link issue in framework bundle for cocoa app

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

Malformed Framework - The framework bundle (nelsonnetbook2.app/Contents/Versions/56.0.2924.76/nwjs Framework.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'nwjs Framework' -> 'Versions/Current/nwjs Framework'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

Malformed Framework - The framework bundle (nelsonnetbook2.app/Contents/Versions/56.0.2924.76/nwjs Framework.framework) must contain a symbolic link 'Resources' -> 'Versions/Current/Resources'. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

Malformed Framework - The framework bundle (nelsonnetbook2.app/Contents/Versions/56.0.2924.76/nwjs Framework.framework) 'Versions' directory must contain a symbolic link 'Current' resolving to a specific version directory. Refer to the Anatomy of Framework Bundles for more information.

I only have a .app file that is created using NWJS

I have also tried

```
ln -s  me.app/Contents/Versions/56.0.2924.76/nwjs Framework.framework me.app/Contents/Resources
```

Can some one tell me how to fix this.

Comment: I’m not sure why you’ve tagged this App Store? Should we get this migrated to stack overflow if you are a developer preparing an app to be submitted to the store?

Comment: yes u correct i am preparing my app to be submitted to appstore and getting error

Comment: i am not able to create perfect symlink...plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **20.0** version of nwjs i tried using **23.6** version with a security update.

This new version already contained symlinks and it worked well with mac app store.